# data structures used behind all the collections in java

Tags: java, data-structures, collections

Recently I was quizzed by interviewer when he asked me to give the data structures behind all the collections in java e.g. ArrayList,Map etc.
Aren't these data structures themselves?
If not, then which data structures back them?

Comment: Each Collection class has a different implementation. For example, ArrayList stores its data in an array. You can look at the code of those classes and see for yourself.

Comment: Those data structures are all (or almost) data arrays at the end.

Comment: I don't think that they have one uber-structure in common, e.g. look at LinkedList and ArrayList. The first one uses nodes with references to the next and previous node, while an ArrayList is backed by an array. You'll find many more differences when looking closer at the implementations

Answer (score 4):

As the [java](/questions/tagged/java) sources provide all the implementation details, I'll just expose a bunch of the most used `collections`:

---

- `java.util.ArrayList<E>`

The implementation of `ArrayList` falls back internally to an `array` of `Object`.

```
/**
 * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
 * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. Any
 * empty ArrayList with elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA
 * will be expanded to DEFAULT_CAPACITY when the first element is added.
 */
transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access
```

Since `arrays` have fixed size, `ArrayList` at each `add` call, recreates, if necessary `elementData` via native calls to `System::arrayCopy`.

---

- `java.util.LinkedList<E>`

`LinkedList`s work over object references rather than `array`s. All items `E` are stored into instances of the internal `class` `Node<E>`:

```
private static class Node<E> {
    E item;
    Node<E> next;
    Node<E> prev;

    Node(Node<E> prev, E element, Node<E> next) {
        this.item = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

where each `Node` keeps a pointer to its next and previous siblings.

A `LinkedList` will only keep a reference to its first and last elements, ergo random access is not supported:

```
/**
 * Pointer to first node.
 * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
 *            (first.prev == null && first.item != null)
 */
transient Node<E> first;

/**
 * Pointer to last node.
 * Invariant: (first == null && last == null) ||
 *            (last.next == null && last.item != null)
 */
transient Node<E> last;
```

---

- `java.util.HashMap<K,V>`

They store keys and values into an internal bundle class `Node<K,V> extends Map.Entry<K,V>`.

Nodes are stored via the function call `HashMap::putVal` into a Node `array`:

```
/**
 * The table, initialized on first use, and resized as
 * necessary. When allocated, length is always a power of two.
 * (We also tolerate length zero in some operations to allow
 * bootstrapping mechanics that are currently not needed.)
 */
transient Node<K,V>[] table;
```

Additionally, `Hashmap`s use a `EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>` collection that constantly reflects the elements in `table`.

```
/**
 * Holds cached entrySet(). Note that AbstractMap fields are used
 * for keySet() and values().
 */
transient Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet;
```

`entrySet` is then exposed as an iterable `collection`:

```
for ( Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : this.myMap.entrySet() ) { /* ... */ }
```

---

- `java.util.HashSet<E>`

Funny thing is `HashSet<T>` uses an `HashMap<T, Object>` which, as we have seen is backed by a `java.util.Set<T>` again.

```
private transient HashMap<E,Object> map;
```

You'll see the body of `HashSet` is kind of limited compared to those of other `java` data structures as most of its operations are just a fallback to its internal `HashMap` structure.

E.g:

`HashSet::add`

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

`HashSet::iterator`

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return map.keySet().iterator();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Underlying data structure for ArrayList is Array, for LinkedList is Link object and for HashMap is Array of LinkedList or Tree. Hope this helps.